# Media query working on resized desktop browser window but not on mobile device

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox, media-queries

I have a wordpress site where I've been adding some emdia queries to handle the mobile version of the website. I'm using Firefox to view the website. Firefox has a feature for developers where you can change the size of the browser (I unfortunately don't know what it's called in english) and I've been using that feature to view how my media queries affect the website.

This is my code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 515px) {

.footer-contact {
    background-color: red;
}

.container {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
footer {
    margin-top: 150px;
}
#hem-kontakt {
    width: 220px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#hem-nummer {
    width: 240px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#hem-kontor {
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#footer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: center;
}
.footer-contact {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.post-container #displayTable {
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: -230px;
}
```

}

If I look at the website in a resized browser window, everything looks fine. But when I look at the website on my phone, it would seem that it is ignoring some of the css in my media queries.

This is what I have done so far:

- I have placed my media queries at the bottom of the css file
- I have looked at the meta-tags in the header.php file and they look like this:

  ```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  ```
- I have emptied the cache in the phone browser
- I have tried three different phones (all android though)
- I've added a *background-color: red;* to the query to see if I get a reaction. I only got a reaction in the browser.

**IMPORTANT**

This code is the most important:

```
.footer-contact {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.post-container #displayTable {
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: -230px;
}
```

In the .post-container #displayTable the mobile recognizes left: 0 and margin-bottom: -230px but it ignores the margin-left and margin-right.

In the .footer-contact it ignores the padding: 0;

I know the mobile places itself in max-width: 515px because it displays the #footer-container as flex (this code)

```
#footer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Those are just code snippets, not enough to reproduce the problem. Please go read [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Too long question is difficult to understand.. show the problem with a single Snippet.

Comment: Some of the problems sound like caching issues. Are you sure the browser reads the latest version of the css?

Comment: It does on the desktop. I have also cleared the cache on the phone multiple times as well as asked people who have never been to the site before to visit it. Still the same issue on mobile.

Comment: Have you tried checking which styles _are_ being applied on mobile? I recommend setting up remote debugging: [iOS (Safari)](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/), [Android (Chrome)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/), [Android (Firefox)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_for_Android_with_WebIDE)

Comment: setup remote debugging and inspect your site directly with phone. maybe the phone load an additional css stylesheet that override your rules